# Gradual positioned boxes in CSS in two columns

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I am building something similiar to this UI for a menu:

[image]

I am searching for a good way to implement it.
I am using bootstrap in this project.
The container is a bootstrap's `container-fluid` inside other DIV which is 50% width of the screen. This is the reason I used `container-fluid` - as this is not fixed width container.

I can work with bootstrap (3) Grid's (col-xx-x), or with any other css solution.

This is what I've done so far, using `float: left`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.menu-items {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-top: -65px;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(even) {
  margin-top: 95px;
}

.image-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span>Item 1</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span>Item 2</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span>Item 3</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span>Item 4</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How would you implement it?

Using float as I did?
Flex is not an option for backward compatibilty issues.
Using bootstrap grid?
Other way?

Comment: Do you have a max height value for the divs or is that also dynamic?

Comment: If you don't want to split your menu items into individual column div's inside your HTML, then this might be the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Ihazkode All the images are the same size. and all texts are one line. so height (and width) is the same for all items

Comment: Is jQuery masonry a suitable option in your case?

Comment: @ihzkode I prefer without another 3rd party plugins (I already have so much).. also, I am using angular which have it's own eco-system that don't play very nice with jQuery, so if any 3rd party - angular based is preferable.. but I am hoping for a custom solution (css based)

Comment: I added my answer on how I would do it with pure CSS and with Masonary.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a *pure CSS* fix then make use of `floating` and **relative** width units or `%`.

Here's a nice simple structure that **doesn't require a lot of code or bootstrap** for that matter.

1. Wrap **the entire setup** in a `.wrapper` div
2. Then...wrap every two `.square` elements in a horizontal `.row`
3. Then... use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selectors to make the necessary
   adjustments for the required offset depending on whether the element
   is the first or second `.square` element inside the `.row` div.

Every `.row` div will always occupy the entire line

Every element inside the `.row` will max-out at 50%... **resize the screen to see what I mean**.

**Working Example:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: grey
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 12% auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square {
  background: black;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color:white;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;

}

.row .square:nth-of-type(1) {
  float: left;
}

.row:not(:nth-of-type(1)) .square:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top: 12%;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 12%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=one">Line for element 1</div>
    <div class="square"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=two">Line for element 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=three">Line for element 3</div>
    <div class="square"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=four">Line for element 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This covers how I would do it with pure CSS.

### Now, this is how I would actually prefer to do it.

I would incorporate / use [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) into the project. Even if the usage might be limited for this particular application. It just makes your design a lot more versatile.

> [...] a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

I know you said you would like to avoid external libraries but...

You can run Masonry [without jQuery:](https://github.com/desandro/vanilla-masonry)

> Masonry v3 supports vanilla JS, without requiring jQuery.

And given that the minified  library is **under 8kb** as can be seen here:

```
https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js
```

it might be a good idea to use it.

Further, you can [initialize the masonry with html alone.](https://masonry.desandro.com/#initialize-in-html) Like so:

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
```

So with all of that out of the way here's what you might end up with...

*Note: (images might be slow to load)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #131418;
}

.grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95vw;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px #131418 solid;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid-item p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-align: justify
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item"}'>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/501/501" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et equidem suscipit delicata eos. Simul scribentur delicatissimi te eam. Ius ea ullum dolorum disputando, pri putent definitiones et. Eos odio deleniti euripidis te, mea ex iudico praesent, et vix accusata percipitur. Ei
      nec quod lorem constituto. Eius intellegebat ad vis. Erat adipiscing conclusionemque mea at, omnesque cotidieque per ea. Oblique philosophia eos id, vel causae appellantur dissentiunt ad. Utroque corpora his an, suas ullamcorper nam ut. Nec iuvaret
      facilisi definiebas ea, ad omnium utamur ius.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/511/511" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit prima oporteat ad, ad ridens tamquam his. Docendi platonem mea te, inani mentitum eum cu, in lorem eripuit debitis eum. Nam ei novum causae cotidieque, placerat similique at per, no his stet ferri animal. An option
      omittam invidunt vim. Dico aperiam cum te, his ei dicit civibus praesent, sed no salutandi hendrerit. Eam te inani verterem honestatis, id sit choro utroque pertinax. Sit cibo duis laoreet et, ea adhuc aliquam eum, mea paulo nostrum atomorum eu.
      Amet habeo semper ex vix, qui ea quas minimum. His at diam quaestio, ut hinc vocent principes eum. Ius sint movet labitur ea, per ad dignissim efficiendi. Idque assum vix at, diceret bonorum impedit eum ei, eos an duis decore deleniti. Duo dictas
      conceptam te.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/522/522" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his altera quodsi everti id. Ex error causae vis, ius ad justo simul nostrud, sea veri recteque ei. Sea et semper percipitur. Ad bonorum interpretaris eos, augue novum legendos vis at. At modus viderer sit, congue fuisset
      postulant ea quo. Ei probatus definitionem sed, cu nam solum quaestio, ad nec debet equidem facilis. No duo essent nusquam vituperata, at duo veri eligendi temporibus. Nam expetenda eloquentiam ut. Habemus conclusionemque in eum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/533/533" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an tollit ocurreret qui, sit no option eleifend periculis. Quo eu suscipit scaevola consulatu, agam essent vituperata in vim. Qui recteque adversarium et, his ad nisl admodum facilisis. Id sit graeco probatus disputationi.
      Blandit ponderum laboramus cu vel. Oblique hendrerit vel ea. Sanctus delenit oportere nec an. Illud equidem voluptaria an ius, cu vidit soleat sit. Vis elit commune ei, qui stet illum repudiare ea. Sint labores neglegentur cu sit, cu alii vocibus
      pri. Ad qui tamquam fabulas oportere, nam consetetur consequuntur delicatissimi ea. Nostro pericula tincidunt usu cu.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/544/544" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, alterum bonorum eum eu, cu ancillae partiendo mei, nec sale quando eloquentiam id. Exerci omittantur eu cum, temporibus repudiandae ad ius. Eos ut diceret alterum, an vix latine reformidans. Has ad tamquam nonumes voluptatibus,
      mucius moderatius id sed. Has tota aperiam feugait at, zril assueverit persequeris has cu. Qui ea rebum maluisset. Omittam oporteat qui ei, ius ea tale quot. Eius probatus laboramus ius ut, aeque quaerendum ei mei. Fierent partiendo cotidieque mel
      at, vis ridens saperet voluptatum ei, ad etiam tantas referrentur eos. Vidit adhuc ius cu, te dicam quaeque sanctus per. Iriure molestie in pro, per ad eius constituam. Ius aliquip sanctus legendos ex, justo aeque abhorreant quo ex. Vis ea movet
      causae /p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/555/555" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tation neglegentur id duo. Ex qui malis moderatius. Nibh efficiantur mea id, qui at porro percipitur. Cum ea mediocrem democritum, te ferri iriure praesent sit, luptatum suscipiantur eam ea. Ex ipsum invenire efficiendi
      ius, an qui mucius tractatos. Vix enim dicat simul cu, pri ei prima tempor numquam. Vim te veri dicat. In mel iusto feugait, eum tale expetendis at, ea sea putant accusamus omittantur. Eos illud utamur referrentur ea. An iisque volumus referrentur
      sit, cu has dicit delenit ancillae. Quod veritus percipitur cu vix, at nec ullum philosophia.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/566/566" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et equidem suscipit delicata eos. Simul scribentur delicatissimi te eam. Ius ea ullum dolorum disputando, pri putent definitiones et. Eos odio deleniti euripidis te, mea ex iudico praesent, et vix accusata percipitur. Ei
      nec quod lorem constituto. Eius intellegebat ad vis. Erat adipiscing conclusionemque mea at, omnesque cotidieque per ea. Oblique philosophia eos id, vel causae appellantur dissentiunt ad. Utroque corpora his an, suas ullamcorper nam ut. Nec iuvaret
      facilisi definiebas ea, ad omnium utamur ius.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/577/577" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit prima oporteat ad, ad ridens tamquam his. Docendi platonem mea te, inani mentitum eum cu, in lorem eripuit debitis eum. Nam ei novum causae cotidieque, placerat similique at per, no his stet ferri animal. An option
      omittam invidunt vim. Dico aperiam cum te, his ei dicit civibus praesent, sed no salutandi hendrerit. Eam te inani verterem honestatis, id sit choro utroque pertinax. Sit cibo duis laoreet et, ea adhuc aliquam eum, mea paulo nostrum atomorum eu.
      Amet habeo semper ex vix, qui ea quas minimum. His at diam quaestio, ut hinc vocent principes eum. Ius sint movet labitur ea, per ad dignissim efficiendi. Idque assum vix at, diceret bonorum impedit eum ei, eos an duis decore deleniti. Duo dictas
      conceptam te.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//unsplash.it/588/588" />
    <p>dum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea, eum eu pdum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus
      molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea, eum eu pdum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis
      forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's **another example** with more generic placeholders. An item will always cover 50% width and the height is dynamic. This one includes the vertical offset in your example picture.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #131418;
}

.grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95vw;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px #131418 solid;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid-item p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-align: justify
}

.grid-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 10em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item"}'>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et equidem suscipit delicata eos. Simul scribentur delicatissimi te eam. Ius ea ullum dolorum disputando, pri putent definitiones et. Eos odio deleniti euripidis te, mea ex iudico praesent, et vix accusata percipitur. Ei
      nec quod lorem constituto. Eius intellegebat ad vis. Erat adipiscing conclusionemque mea at, omnesque cotidieque per ea. Oblique philosophia eos id, vel causae appellantur dissentiunt ad. Utroque corpora his an, suas ullamcorper nam ut. Nec iuvaret
      facilisi definiebas ea, ad omnium utamur ius.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x500" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit prima oporteat ad, ad ridens tamquam his. Docendi platonem mea te, inani mentitum eum cu, in lorem eripuit debitis eum. Nam ei novum causae cotidieque, placerat similique at per, no his stet ferri animal. An option
      omittam invidunt vim. Dico aperiam cum te, his ei dicit civibus praesent, sed no salutandi hendrerit. Eam te inani verterem honestatis, id sit choro utroque pertinax. Sit cibo duis laoreet et, ea adhuc aliquam eum, mea paulo nostrum atomorum eu.
      Amet habeo semper ex vix, qui ea quas minimum. His at diam quaestio, ut hinc vocent principes eum. Ius sint movet labitur ea, per ad dignissim efficiendi. Idque assum vix at, diceret bonorum impedit eum ei, eos an duis decore deleniti. Duo dictas
      conceptam te.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/600x600" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his altera quodsi everti id. Ex error causae vis, ius ad justo simul nostrud, sea veri recteque ei. Sea et semper percipitur. Ad bonorum interpretaris eos, augue novum legendos vis at. At modus viderer sit, congue fuisset
      postulant ea quo. Ei probatus definitionem sed, cu nam solum quaestio, ad nec debet equidem facilis. No duo essent nusquam vituperata, at duo veri eligendi temporibus. Nam expetenda eloquentiam ut. Habemus conclusionemque in eum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/700x700" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an tollit ocurreret qui, sit no option eleifend periculis. Quo eu suscipit scaevola consulatu, agam essent vituperata in vim. Qui recteque adversarium et, his ad nisl admodum facilisis. Id sit graeco probatus disputationi.
      Blandit ponderum laboramus cu vel. Oblique hendrerit vel ea. Sanctus delenit oportere nec an. Illud equidem voluptaria an ius, cu vidit soleat sit. Vis elit commune ei, qui stet illum repudiare ea. Sint labores neglegentur cu sit, cu alii vocibus
      pri. Ad qui tamquam fabulas oportere, nam consetetur consequuntur delicatissimi ea. Nostro pericula tincidunt usu cu.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/450x450" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, alterum bonorum eum eu, cu ancillae partiendo mei, nec sale quando eloquentiam id. Exerci omittantur eu cum, temporibus repudiandae ad ius. Eos ut diceret alterum, an vix latine reformidans. Has ad tamquam nonumes voluptatibus,
      mucius moderatius id sed. Has tota aperiam feugait at, zril assueverit persequeris has cu. Qui ea rebum maluisset. Omittam oporteat qui ei, ius ea tale quot. Eius probatus laboramus ius ut, aeque quaerendum ei mei. Fierent partiendo cotidieque mel
      at, vis ridens saperet voluptatum ei, ad etiam tantas referrentur eos. Vidit adhuc ius cu, te dicam quaeque sanctus per. Iriure molestie in pro, per ad eius constituam. Ius aliquip sanctus legendos ex, justo aeque abhorreant quo ex. Vis ea movet
      causae /p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/550x550" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tation neglegentur id duo. Ex qui malis moderatius. Nibh efficiantur mea id, qui at porro percipitur. Cum ea mediocrem democritum, te ferri iriure praesent sit, luptatum suscipiantur eam ea. Ex ipsum invenire efficiendi
      ius, an qui mucius tractatos. Vix enim dicat simul cu, pri ei prima tempor numquam. Vim te veri dicat. In mel iusto feugait, eum tale expetendis at, ea sea putant accusamus omittantur. Eos illud utamur referrentur ea. An iisque volumus referrentur
      sit, cu has dicit delenit ancillae. Quod veritus percipitur cu vix, at nec ullum philosophia.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/650x650" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et equidem suscipit delicata eos. Simul scribentur delicatissimi te eam. Ius ea ullum dolorum disputando, pri putent definitiones et. Eos odio deleniti euripidis te, mea ex iudico praesent, et vix accusata percipitur. Ei
      nec quod lorem constituto. Eius intellegebat ad vis. Erat adipiscing conclusionemque mea at, omnesque cotidieque per ea. Oblique philosophia eos id, vel causae appellantur dissentiunt ad. Utroque corpora his an, suas ullamcorper nam ut. Nec iuvaret
      facilisi definiebas ea, ad omnium utamur ius.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/750x750" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit prima oporteat ad, ad ridens tamquam his. Docendi platonem mea te, inani mentitum eum cu, in lorem eripuit debitis eum. Nam ei novum causae cotidieque, placerat similique at per, no his stet ferri animal. An option
      omittam invidunt vim. Dico aperiam cum te, his ei dicit civibus praesent, sed no salutandi hendrerit. Eam te inani verterem honestatis, id sit choro utroque pertinax. Sit cibo duis laoreet et, ea adhuc aliquam eum, mea paulo nostrum atomorum eu.
      Amet habeo semper ex vix, qui ea quas minimum. His at diam quaestio, ut hinc vocent principes eum. Ius sint movet labitur ea, per ad dignissim efficiendi. Idque assum vix at, diceret bonorum impedit eum ei, eos an duis decore deleniti. Duo dictas
      conceptam te.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/1400x1400" />
    <p>dum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea, eum eu pdum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus
      molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea, eum eu pdum suavitate argumentum, an qui facer facete, persius veritus molestiae cum cu. Mei vitae consequat at, usu te novum facilisis
      forensibus. Pri minim reformidans accommodare ea</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: [Angular has something similar](https://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/) but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using pure CSS, via `float` and `clear`, you just need to add `margin`s to your blocks. Demo:

```css
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.a,
.c {
  float: left;
}

.c {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.b,
.d {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.container {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 30px;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.item {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item a">One</div>
  <br class="clear" />
  <div class="item b">Two</div>
  <br class="clear" />
  <div class="item c">Three</div>
  <br class="clear" />
  <div class="item d">Four</div>
  <br class="clear" />
</div>
```